# symfony2 + doctrine: modify a child entity on `onFlush`: "Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `1:m` relationship between `Subitem` and `SubitemColor`. Now I would like to save some data inside an `onFlush` to modify some data for `SubitemColor`. The problem: I get the error message below when executing the controller you can see below too:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO SubitemColor
>   (code, precio, pvp_recommended, file_name, activado, en_stock, area,
>   lets_fix_width_or_height_in_list, lets_fix_width_or_height_in_show,
>   position_level_0, position_level_1, position_brand, subitem_id,
>   color_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with
>   params [2]:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
>   does not match number of tokens

```
  public function onFlush(Event \OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)
  {
    $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    $updates = $uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates();
    $insertions = $uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions();

    /////////// NEW SUBITEM_IMAGE OR SUBITEM_COLOR UPLOADED //////////
    foreach ($insertions as $entity) {


      if ($entity instanceof SubitemColor) {
        //$entity->setLetsFixWidthOrHeightInList("jander");
        //$entity->setLetsFixWidthOrHeightInList('width');
        //$entity->setLetsFixWidthOrHeightInShow('width');

        $entity->setEnStock(2);

        $metaSubitemColor = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));

        $uow->computeChangeSet($metaSubitemColor, $entity);

        $uow->persist($entity);
      }
    }
  }

//controller - controller - controller - controller
    $subitem = new Subitem();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $subitem->setNombre("jls");
    $subitemColor = new SubitemColor();
    $subitem->addSubitemColor($subitemColor);

    $em->persist($subitem);
    $em->persist($subitemColor);

    $metaSubitem = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($subitem));
    $em->flush();
```

Comment: Why do you use `$metaSubitem = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($subitem));` in controller?

Comment: `onFlush(Event \OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)` this prototype is not possible.

Comment: @ziiweb - I replicated your problem and updated my answer below to demonstrate how you can solve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet` method instead of `computeChangeSet`

`computeChangeSet` method is supposed to be called by doctrine only and calls once for every entity that marked for persistence on flush operation.

When you load entity from database doctrine saves its data to `originalEntityData` array, then it checks if no original data exists for entity then this entity is new and doctrine saves its current data as original and fill change set with every field value.

On second call of `computeChangeSet` doctrine has original data for newly created entity and computes change set only for changed fields since last call of `computeChangeSet` method.

Thats why you should never call `computeChangeSet`.

Comment: what about using both ?

Answer (score 1):

I replicated your problem as you can see in the image below.

[image]

The problem is; `persist()` is being used once in your controller (which you cannot do without it) and once in your `onFlush()` listener (which you cannot do without it as well!!!) so for that reason you get that error.

> Event onFlush is called inside `EntityManager#flush()` after the
>   changes to all the managed entities and their associations have been
>   computed.

You're calling persist in your controller and straight after that you're calling another persist in your listener before even flushing it in your controller.

**SOLUTION**

Based on what you're trying to do, `onFlush` is not what you need anyway so the one you should use is `prePersist` so look at the example below.

**CONTROLLER**

Please checkout entity examples I added at the bottom. As you noted it is 1:N so since child `SubitemColor` cannot exist without parent `Subitem`, we're using `$subitemColor->setSubitem($subitem);` oppose to your example.

```
public function createAction()
{
    $subitem = new Subitem();
    $subitemColor = new SubitemColor();

    $subitem->setNombre('jls');
    $subitemColor->setSubitem($subitem);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($subitem);
    $em->persist($subitemColor);
    $em->flush();
}
```

**YML**

```
services:
    application_backend.event_listener.subitem:
        class: Application\BackendBundle\EventListener\SubitemListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

**LISTENER**

```
namespace Application\BackendBundle\EventListener;

use Application\BackendBundle\Entity\SubitemColor;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class SubitemListener
{
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if ($entity instanceof SubitemColor) {
            $entity->setEnStock(2);
        }
    }
}
```

**RESULT**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM subitem;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM subitem_color;
Empty set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM subitem;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | jls  |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM subitem_color;
+----+------------+------+----------+
| id | subitem_id | code | en_stock |
+----+------------+------+----------+
|  1 |          1 | NULL |        2 |
+----+------------+------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

**SUBITEM ENTITY**

```
namespace Application\BackendBundle\Entity;

use Application\BackendBundle\Entity\SubitemColor;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="subitem")
 */
class Subitem
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=20)
     */
    protected $nombre;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SubitemColor", mappedBy="subitem", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $subitemColor;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->subitemColor = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $nombre
     * @return Subitem
     */
    public function setNombre($nombre)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNombre()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @param SubitemColor $subitemColor
     * @return Subitem
     */
    public function addSubitemColor(SubitemColor $subitemColor)
    {
        $this->subitemColor[] = $subitemColor;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param SubitemColor $subitemColor
     */
    public function removeSubitemColor(SubitemColor $subitemColor)
    {
        $this->subitemColor->removeElement($subitemColor);
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getSubitemColor()
    {
        return $this->subitemColor;
    }
}
```

**SUBITEMCOLOR ENTITY**

```
namespace Application\BackendBundle\Entity;

use Application\BackendBundle\Entity\Subitem;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="subitem_color")
 */
class SubitemColor
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="en_stock", type="integer", length=5, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $enStock;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Subitem", inversedBy="subitemColor")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="subitem_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $subitem;

    /**
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $code
     * @return SubitemColor
     */
    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    /**
     * @param integer $enStock
     * @return SubitemColor
     */
    public function setEnStock($enStock)
    {
        $this->enStock = $enStock;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getEnStock()
    {
        return $this->enStock;
    }

    /**
     * @param Subitem $subitem
     * @return SubitemColor
     */
    public function setSubitem(Subitem $subitem)
    {
        $this->subitem = $subitem;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Subitem
     */
    public function getSubitem()
    {
        return $this->subitem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not solve your problem, but when I do this in my code I call `$uow->persist($entity);` *then* I call `$uow->computeChangeSet($metaSubitemColor, $entity);`

Order seems important here as you have persisted changes that then have to be recalculated in the unit of work. So persisting after calling computeChangeSet seems likely to cause problems.